# Get special character from Query string in classic asp

Tags: url, asp-classic

I have an URL like  `ViewProfile.asp?mem_id=phani#1&page=1`

I am trying to get the value of `mem_id` by using `request.Querystring("mem_id")`, I am getting only phani. The part #1 of it is not coming to the variable.

I have used `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`  and  `Server.UrlDecode()`. I am not sure whether these are there.

Can someone help me how to get the query string with special character also?

Comment: # is reserved symbol and must be percent encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got where I am going wrong. 
while giving the redirection tag like

`<a href='ViewProfile.asp?mem_id=phani#1&page=1'>`

it should be like  `<a href='ViewProfile.asp?mem_id=Server.UrlEncode(phani#1)&page=1'>`

This solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can *decode* the URL, the value must be *encoded* in the first place.  To be properly formed, that URL should be:

```
ViewProfile.asp?mem_id=phani%231&page=1
```

The `#` (hash) character [has a specific meaning in URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).  When the request is made to the server, the browser isn't even sending that part.  That's something the browser uses to identify a specific part of the page to navigate to.

As it stands, the server-side code is behaving correctly.  It's simply being provided with bad input.